# How to disable search key and camera key while displaying menu?

Tags: android, menu, controls, keycode

I've created a menu in my one activity as follows:

/menu/my_menu_list.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/mn_about" android:title="About"
            android:icon="@drawable/about" />
        <item android:id="@+id/mn_display_list" android:title="Display List"
            android:icon="@drawable/display_list" />
    </menu>
```

Also overriden these methods.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu_list, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mn_about:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
                break;

            case R.id.mn_display_list:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplayList.class));
                break;
            }
        }
```

Those work perfect. Now I need to disable search key and camera key while displaying this menu. The following code works fine for an activity but I don't know where to put this code for menu.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)) {
                return false;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

**Edit 1**

I disabled the camera for whole application. For this, I added following receiver tag in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="12000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="11000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also created a Receiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

This solved for the camera but not working for long press search and voice dialer.

**Edit 2**
I also tried following way to control Long_Press_Search key. But not working.

```
    public class MyMenuInflater extends MenuInflater implements OnKeyListener {

        public MyMenuInflater(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                Log.d("KeyPress", "search");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
   }
```

And changed onCreateOptionsMenu() as follows.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MyMenuInflater inflater=new MyMenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu_list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It does not capture the keypress event.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Is there any way to control those keys for whole application at once?